# Cambiar versión de java

Tags: java, windows10

Tengo un problema para abrir un fichero de configuración de hibernate, el cual me dice que el eclipse se está ejecutando en una versión mayor a la del proyecto, voy a comprobar y veo que aunque tengo el proyecto en Java 7, mi versión de java funcionando es la 8.

He cambiado la variable de entorno, he cambiado en la consola de configuración de java, y todavía sigue saliendo java 8, que me queda?

CMD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Panel de control de Java:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Variable del sistema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No comprendo como puede seguir saliendo la 8 cuando hago java -version en mi consola de comandos.

Comment: No soy un experto en esto pero algo he trabajado con eclipse. Dicho esto, supongo que compilaras el proyecto. Si es así, al darle a compilar y seleccionar el perfil, hay una pestaña antes de confirmar, en la parte superior de la ventanita, donde te permite elegir la versión de java. Da igual que tengas puesto que es la 7, como eclipse diga que coge la 8, te lo hace con la 8. Míralo, si puedes, que tampoco me he explicado muy bien, y me dices.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ir a Eclipse:

> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí puedes cambiar la versión de Java

Comment: Era un problema de variables de entorno y de configuración de w10, ya habia intentado lo de cambiar desde eclipse. La solución ha sido compilar y ejecutar desde cmd. Muchas gracias igualmente.